# Como hacer que una aplicacion Java swing caduque despues de un determinado tiempo?

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenos dias, sucede que tengo mi aplicacion Java Swing.... Y se las voy a instalar a varios clientes que quieren conocerla y probar para saber si les gusta y deciden comprarmela... Pero como puedo hacer para que la aplicacion inicie durante un mes y luego deje de iniciar... 

**Pensaba hacer que la aplicacion lea la fecha actual desde el pc o de internet y que la compare con la que yo programe la aplicacion, pero en caso tal de que el computador no tenga internet, la aplicacion trabajara con la del computador, pero la fecha del computador tambien se puede cambiar manualmente...**

Como puedo hacer? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una Alternativa es hacer una validación a nivel de red, por ejemplo colocar como modelo de negocio que el **periodo de prueba requiera de conexión a Internet**, de tal manera que creas un pequeño servicio o código para **validar la fecha** cada ves que ingrese al usuario en un login o simplemente al abrir la aplicación en este momento el aplicativo(software) validará la fecha, si cumple con el periodo(rango de fecha establecido) está abrirá, si no cumple o no se puede conectar a la red, no permitirá su uso.

Espero sea de utilidad!, Saludos